# How do I update a property on page load after ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app that pulls in a list from firebase ngOnInit to page A.  When I navigate away from the page A and update the list on a different page B, then when I navigate back to page A the list doesn't have the updates.  I have to close the app then re-open it to get the updated list.  I've tried several different lifecycle Angular hooks to no avail.

Is there a lifecycle on a simple page load after it's been initialized?  How can I check the updated list whenever I navigate back to that page?

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSvc.getItineraries()
    .get()
    .then( itineraryListSnapshot => {
      this.matchItinerary = [];
      itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.matchItinerary.push({
          id: snap.id,
          activities: snap.data().activities,
          destination: snap.data().destination,
          startDate: snap.data().startDate,
          endDate: snap.data().endDate,
          tripDetails: snap.data().tripDetails,
          userId: snap.data().userId
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Yes, I'm actually loading the data from a service that doesn't get destroyed.

Here is the actual service

```js
    getItineraries(): firebase.firestore.CollectionReference {
      return this.itineraryCollection;
    }
```

The collection is created in the constructor of the service and just returns all of the user's list.

Comment: Looks like you either loading your data to a service which doesn't get destroyed and keeps the data or not destroying the page on leaving it. You can check your component's lifecycle using `ngOnDestroy` and `ngOnInit` to check whether the component is destroyed on page leave and re-initialized on coming back. Then continue exploring code. Also it's worth considering to use IDE Debug tools to track the data flow etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm loading it from a service and using that same service to update the list from a different page.  I've looked at the lifecycle hooks and they all only get invoked once on page load.

Comment: In that case the easiest way I see without seeing your code is providing `Subject` in a service which `.next` will cause your component to reload the data.

Comment: Also if `snap.data()` is a function call I would consider placing it's results in a local variable and using destructuring to call it once instead of many (much better for performance)

Comment: I added the service.  How would I do that with subject?

Comment: What is `this.itineraryCollection;` and how it actually gets the value?

Comment: It's just a firebase collection created in the constructor of the service:

this.itineraryCollection = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary/${user.uid}/itineraryList`);

Comment: Please check if getItineraries() in the service is called if you navigate back to the page. I assume that ngOnInit() is not called when navigating back in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` returns a Promise and because Ionic caches pages (if you use Ionics `router-outlet` and I assume you do, because if you wouldn't, component would be destroyed after you leave it and `OnInit` would be called again after you visit it). So when you again visit component, `OnInit` is not called. Luckily Firestore gives as `onSnapshot()` which observes changes in your collection:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSvc.getItineraries()
    .onSnapshot( (itineraryListSnapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {
      this.matchItinerary = [];
      itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.matchItinerary.push({
          id: snap.id,
          activities: snap.data().activities,
          destination: snap.data().destination,
          startDate: snap.data().startDate,
          endDate: snap.data().endDate,
          tripDetails: snap.data().tripDetails,
          userId: snap.data().userId
        });
      });
    });
```

*you can also provide `error` callback. [Read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#onsnapshot)*

*p.s. and you might want to use [docChanges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#docchanges), but probably you wont need it with `onSnapshot()` method.*